# An apache error with LDAP Server on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, apache-2.4, ldap, svn, redmine

I have a trouble need your help here.

I want to connect my Apache and SVN to my LDAP Server, but when I want to commit my code and I type the right password, the Apache server will show the error log

```
[Tue Apr 26 18:08:02.086954 2016] [auth_basic:error] [pid 3756:tid 1060] [client 192.168.10.72:55780] AH01617: user parker: authentication failure for "/svn/!svn/me": Password Mismatch     
[Tue Apr 26 18:08:04.317754 2016] [auth_basic:error] [pid 3756:tid 1060] [client 192.168.10.72:55780] AH01617: user parker: authentication failure for "/svn/!svn/me": Password Mismatch
```

here is my condition

> Server_windows server 2008 R2.
>   o Redmine : 3.2.1-0
>   o Apache : 2.4.18.0
>   o Subversion : 1.8.13
>   o MySQL : 5.5.48
>
> Client_win7
>   o Visual Studio 2008
>   o AnkhSvn : 2.5.12703

I edit my httpd.conf in "C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.2.1-0\apache2\conf" like

```
<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNPath c:\svndata
AuthzSVNAccessFile c:\svndata\conf\authz
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthName test.com

SVNListParentPath On
SVNAutoversioning On
SVNReposName "Your Subversion Repository1"
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Your Subversion Repository2"

LDAPReferrals off
AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative on
AuthLDAPBindDN "dc=test,dc=com"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "P@ssw0rd"
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://192.168.10.1:389/dc=test,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
</Location>
```

And I edit my authz in "C:\svndata\conf" like

```
[/]
parker = rw
* = r
```

NOTE:

> 1. authz file mean every one can read the code, but only user "parker" can write.
> 2. I konw my LDAP Server is work, because I could connect Redmine(aother software) with LDAP Server.
> 3. I find some bug from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751242/apache-2-4-authentication-failure-password-mismatch,
>      or from
>      https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=9839, both
>      of that looks like my error, but my Apache's version is 2.4.18, it's 
>      under then 2.4.4...and they didn't use LDAP... By the wey, my OS is
>      windows...

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you all for your help!

Comment: `Password Mismatch` !!!

Answer (score 0):

I try it done! And its work now.
This error can be fix that if I designation ***`cn=parker,ou=group`***

> AuthLDAPBindDN "***`cn=parker,ou=group`***,dc=test,dc=com"
>
> AuthLDAPBindPassword "Password"

thank you all